Equivalence of convergence of two sequences $\{x_n\}$ and $\{y_n\}$ with $y_{n+1}=\sqrt{x_n+y_n}$.
Suppose $\{x_n\}$ and $\{y_n\}$ are two positive sequences with
$$y_1=0,\quad y_{n+1}=\sqrt{x_n+y_n},$$ then $\{x_n\}$ is convergent if and only if $\{y_n\}$ is convergent.
The following is my proof using the Upper and lower limits，is my proof right and are there  other methods to deal with this question. Any hints or comments will welcome.
Proof: If $\{y_n\}$ is convergent, it is easy to see $\{x_n\}$ is convergent due to
$$x_n=y^2_{n+1}-y_n.$$
Now suppose $\{x_n\}$ is convergent. Let
$$x=\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n,\quad \liminf_{n\to\infty}y_n=y,\quad \limsup_{n\to\infty}y_n=Y.$$
From the equation
$$y^2_{n+1}=x_n+y_n,$$
we can get
$$y^2\geq x+y,\tag{1}$$
$$Y^2\leq x+Y.\tag{2}$$
From $(1)$, we get $$y\geq\frac{1+\sqrt{1+4x}}{2},$$
from $(2)$, we get $$0\leq Y\leq\frac{1+\sqrt{1+4x}}{2}.$$
Due to $y\leq Y$, we can get $$y=Y=\frac{1+\sqrt{1+4x}}{2}.$$
Added: Thanks  @ Alain Remillard @ Evan_Bradley for their valuable comment. Here gives the proof that $\{y_n\}$ is bounded above.
Proof: As $\{x_n\}$ is convergent, then there exists $M>0$ such that
$$0<x_n\leq M,\quad \forall n\in\mathbb N.$$
Let $$z_1=0,\quad z_{n+1}=\sqrt{z_n+M},\quad\forall n\geq1,$$
then $\{z_n\}$ is convergent and $y_n\leq z_n,\forall n\geq1$.
Hence, $\{y_n\}$ is bounded above and $\limsup_{n\to\infty}y_n$ exists.

What made you think that $\lim\sup y_n$ exists? IMO this is what is missing.

Add one part that shows ${y_n}$ is bounded above.

@
Evan_Bradley You are right , I should prove ${y_n}$ is bounded above.Thank you!

By the way that's a nice result !
